# How to set focus on textbox and button simultaneously in WinForm

Tags: winforms, user-interface

I want to set focus on a button while caret is present in textbox and user can still enter data to textbox. But when user presses enter key, button press will be simulated.

I am currently using a work around to solve this problem by handling onKeyDown event and checking for enter key. But problem is there is no clue for user to understand this as there is not blue border around the button that indicates focus on button.

Here is a example of what I want to implement (user can enter text in textbox while focus is on :
[image: Dialog Box with focus on button and caret in textbox]

I have tried to search on google and StackOverflow but could not find any relevant result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fundamental Windows principle. It's not possible to have 2 controls (windows) focused at the same time.

So the focus should be inside the text box. But you can get the visual indication needed by setting the ok button as [`AcceptButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) of the form (you might also want to set cancel button as [`CancelButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)).

In the form constructor, load event or using designer:

```
this.AcceptButton = okButton;
```

There is no need to handle `KeyDown` event - as soon as the text box is not multiline, pressing `Enter` while the focus is inside it will generate ok button click. The same applies for the button set as `CancelButton` when you press `ESC`.